# when and where do we use session_id()

Tags: php, session, sessionid

I can't understand the code below and I don't know when we use `session_id()` before `session_start()` .

```
<?php
if($_GET){
    //defining the session_id() before session_start() is the secret
    session_id($_GET['session_id']);
    session_start();
    echo "Data: " . $_SESSION['theVar'];
    //use your data before below commands
    session_destroy();
    session_commit();
}else{
    //common session statement goes here
    session_start();
    $session_id=session_id();
    $_SESSION['theVar'] = "theData";
    echo "your.php?session_id=" . $session_id;
}
?>
```

i want you to  explain it ! not just copying the description of php.net !
 on the other hand , where is  session_id() used ?! what's its usage ?! 
thank you in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finally i understood  ! i give you two examples :

```
<?php 
session_start();
session_id();
?>
```

*result* |stbug36ge9efg20cpdjnq83m50 ( session id )

and whenever the browser or tab is closed , the session will be omitted and the next time you enter the site , you can manage two action  to occur  :
1. start a new session with previous session_id 
2. or start a new session witt a new id 
as the usual , the action num.2 will happen but if you want num.1 to happen you have to embed session_id before session_start . look at the code below :

```
<?php
session_id("stbug36ge9efg20cpdjnq83m50");
session_start();

?>
```

and here we're starting a new session with previous session id .

and

**the usage of Session_id()**

you can easily write a online  visitors counter -- each time a session starts(use is online ) , its id will store in database . so we can find out how many users are online.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the session id before starting the session lets you manually "resume" a session, so to speak.  If you session_start() without setting the ID, and the previous session has expired, it will generate a new ID and start a brand new session.

**From the PHP documentation:**

> If id is specified, it will replace the current session id. session_id() needs to be called before session_start() for that purpose.

See more at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Comment: session_start doesn't always generate a new ID.  If a session already exists, it will resume that session.

Comment: Revised my answer as I wasn't clear.  Thanks for pointing that out. ;)

Comment: @BenFried , actually i haven't understood yet :-( . can you give me an instance?!

Answer (score 1):

The **[manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php)** is a good place to start.  session_id isn't required to start or manage sessions.  PHP and the browser (through a cookie) will usually handle this automatically if you exclude session_id.  You can however maintain multiple sessions per end user by specifying a session ID.